# Prevent Duplicate Entries into ListView/Access DB

Tags: c#, listview

I want to scan in serial numbers into a listview which stores the data into an access db.  When the user clicks Submit, the program should either store the data or display a message that indicates the serial number was a duplicate.   Here is my code:

Here is how I connect to the database:

```
namespace Serial_Number_Checker
{
     public partial class Form1:Form
     {
         static string conString = ""
         OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(conString);
         OleDbCommand cmd;
         OleDbDataAdapter adapter;
         DataTable dt = new DataTable();
```

Here is how I create columns for the listview:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        listView1.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(listView1_SelectedIndexChanged); // Adding columns to listView1

        // list view properities
        listView1.View = View.Details;
        listView1.FullRowSelect = true;

        // Add Columns
        listView1.Columns.Add("Employee #", 150);
        listView1.Columns.Add("Serial Number", 150);
        listView1.Columns.Add("Date/Time", 150);            
    }
```

Here is the Add to listView portion:

```
    // Add To ListView1
    private void populate(String employeeid, String sn, String timestamp)
    {
        // Row
        String[] row = { employeeid, sn, timestamp };

        ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(row);

        listView1.Items.Add(item);
    }
```

Here is the retrieve function:

```
    // Retrieve Check In
    private void retrieve()
    {
        listView1.Items.Clear();

        //Sql statement
        String sql = "Select * FROM SN_Incoming";
        cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, con);

        //Open connection, retrieve, and fill listview1
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);

            adapter.Fill(dt);

            //Loop thru dt
            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                populate(row[0].ToString(), row[1].ToString(), row[2].ToString());
            }

            con.Close();

            //Clear datatable
            dt.Rows.Clear();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            con.Close();
        }
    }
```

This is the submit button portion:

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (ListViewItem itemSelected in listView1.SelectedItems)
    {
        listView1.Items.Remove(itemSelected);
    }

    if (textBox1.Text == "")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please Enter A Serial Number!", "Input");
    }

    else
    {
        add(textBox1.Text);
    }


    textBox1.Text = "";
    textBox1.Focus(); // Set Focus
    textBox1.SelectionStart = textBox1.Text.Length == 0 ? 0 : textBox1.Text.Length - 1; // set text selection to end
    textBox1.SelectionLength = 0; // Set text Selection Length

    retrieve();
}
```

This should be most of the code.  Anything helps.

Comment: You need to add a bit more to your question. What is `add()`? what is `retrieve()`? Where's the part where you connect to the database? Don't show all your code, though, just enough to show what you need to do.

Comment: I have added the code for retrieve and add.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my understanding you want to prevent adding duplicate records to your `ListView` control. I will cover preventing duplicates in your `ListView` and in your `Access Database`.

***ListView***

I would handle this by assigning the serial number to the `Tag` property of each `ListViewItem` prior to adding it to the control. Then to ensure no duplicates are added, I would then use that `Tag` as a reference point for the new serial number to be added. For example:

```
// Make sure you include the using statement at the top of your code file.
using System.Linq;

private void populate(string employeeid, string, sn, string timestamp) {
    ListViewItem lvi = listView1.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>()
                                      .SingleOrDefault(s => s.Tag == sn);
    if (lvi == null) {
        lvi = new ListViewItem(employeeid);
        lvi.SubItems.Add(sn);
        lvi.SubItems.Add(timestamp);
        lvi.Tag = sn;
        listView1.Items.Add(lvi);
    } else
        MessageBox.Show("Serial number supplied already exists.");
}
```

The solution above utilizes `LINQ` which stands for [Language Integrated Query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/). It was introduced in .NET 3.5. The method utilized essentially attempts to find a `ListViewItem` that contains the `Tag` property with a value of the supplied serial number.

The call [to](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406(v=vs.110).aspx) `Cast` allows you to utilize the `SingleOrDefault` [method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342451(v=vs.110).aspx) available to `IEnumerable` since the `Items` [property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.items(v=vs.110).aspx) of `ListView` does not derive from `IEnumerable`, but instead `ListViewItemCollection`.

You can take this down to a lower level of .NET by implementing a `foreach` loop instead of utilizing `LINQ`. For example:

```
private void populate(string employeeid, string, sn, string timestamp) {
    foreach (ListViewItem lvi in listView1.Items) {
        if (lvi.Tag == sn) {
            MessageBox.Show("Serial number supplied already exists.");
            return;
        }
    }

    // We know the serial number doesn't exist, so just add the new item.
    ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(employeeid);
    lvi.SubItems.Add(sn);
    lvi.SubItems.Add(timestamp);
    lvi.Tag = sn;
    listView1.Items.Add(lvi);
}
```

***Database***

Since you're using Access for your database, you can follow [this](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/prevent-duplicate-values-in-a-field-b5eaace7-6161-4edc-bb90-39d1a1bc5576) guide on preventing duplicate values in a column (in your case it will prevent duplicate serial numbers). Essentially, you just create a unique index for the field you wish to have unique. This is done by setting the field's `Indexed` property to `Yes`.

> Set a field's Indexed property to Yes (No duplicates)
>
> 1. In the Navigation Pane, right-click the table that contains the field, and then click Design View.
> 2. Select the field that you want to make sure has unique values.
> 3. In the Field Properties pane, on the General tab, set the Indexed property to Yes (No duplicates).

***Useful Points***

1. `LINQ` expressions are broken down by the compiler to their basic implementations. For example, `SingleOrDefault` loops through a collection of objects, attempts to find a single object that meets the specified criteria, and then returns the result. If no object was found, it returns `null`. This is done with a `foreach` loop.
2. The `foreach` loop is actually faster than using `LINQ` in most cases. On a small scale this wouldn't even be noticed; however, increase the number of `ListViewItem` objects that you have to iterate through into the 300,000+ range and you have a substantial difference.
3. Also, it is more effective to add all of your `ListViewItem` objects to a generic collection, then finally to the `ListView` via `AddRange`. If I remember correctly, this is because `Add` and `AddRange` cause the `ListView` to re-sort, and as point 2 above stated, the more items you have, the worse this impacts performance. I've included an example of this kind of implementation below:

***Add Range Implementation***

```
List<ListViewItem> items = new List<ListViewItem>();
for (int i = 0; i < 50000; i++) {
    ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem($"Some kind of text {i}.");
    lvi.Tag = i;
    items.Add(lvi);
}
listView1.Items.AddRange(items.ToArray());
```

***Refactor Of Your Code***

I took the liberty of refactoring your code to teach you more simplistic/efficient ways to accomplish your goal. You may want to take a look at the documentation for: [using statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement), [string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace(v=vs.110).aspx), [string.Empty](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.empty(v=vs.110).aspx). The one thing I will clue you in on with the `using` statement is that it will automatically close any open connections when the final portion of the block is executed, this is due to the disposal of the object:

> When the lifetime of an `IDisposable` object is limited to a single method, you should declare and instantiate it in the `using` statement. The `using` statement calls the [Dispose](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.idisposable.dispose?view=netframework-4.7.2) method on the object in the correct way, and (when you use it as shown earlier) it also causes the object itself to go out of scope as soon as [Dispose](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.idisposable.dispose?view=netframework-4.7.2) is called. Within the `using` block, the object is read-only and cannot be modified or reassigned.

```
private void Click_Submit(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    foreach (ListViewItem lvi in listView1.SelectedItems)
        listView1.Items.Remove(lvi);

    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox1.Text))
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a serial number!", "Input");
    else
        InserSerialNumber(textBox1.Text);

    textBox1.Text = string.Empty;
    textBox1.Focus();
    textBox1.SelectionStart = textBox1.Text.Length == 0 ? 0 : textBox1.Text.Length - 1;
    textBox1.SelectionLength = 0;

    LoadSerialNumbers();
}
private void InsertSerialNumber(string sn) {
    using (OleDbCommand odc = new OleDbCommand("INSER INTO SN_Incoming(SN) VALUES(@SN)", con)) {
        odc.Parameters.AddWIthValue("@SN", sn);
        try {
            con.Open();
            odc.ExecuteNonQuery();
        } catch (Exception e) { MessageBox.Show(e.Message); } finally { con.Close(); }
    }
}
private void LoadSerialNumbers() {
    listView1.Items.Clear();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    using (OleDbCommand odc = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM SN_Incoming", con)) {
        try {
            con.Open();
            using (OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter(odc))
                ida.Fill(dt);
        } catch (Exception e) { MessageBox.Show(e.Message); } finally { con.Close(); }
    }

    List<ListViewItem> items = new List<ListViewItem>();
    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows) {
        ListViewItem lvi = items.SingleOrDefault(s => s.Tag == row[1].ToString());
        if (lvi != null)
            continue;

        lvi = new ListViewItem(new string[] { row[0].ToString(), row[1].ToString(), row[2].ToString() });
        lvi.Tag = row[1].ToString();
        items.Add(lvi);
    }

    listView1.Items.AddRange(items.ToArray());
}
```

Comment: Would this code replace the section of code I have for button1_click?  Tried to implement the code but no luck.

Comment: This code will replace the code in your populate method, and to stick to your current implementation I have updated the post to allow you to call the method the same as before.

Comment: I was able to prevent duplicates in the Access database but now when a duplicate is entered in the listView1, I get an error message from access...  thoughts?

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: I will give this a go.  The error message reads: "The changes you requested to the table were not successful because they would create duplicate values in the index, primary key, or relationship.  Change the data in the field or fields that contain duplicate data, remove the index, ore redefine the index to permit duplicate entries and try again."

Comment: You'll have to remove any existing duplicate entries when changing the `Indexing` property. The code posted above, especially the refactor should give you exactly what you need. You'll just have to manually remove any existing duplicates from your database, then manually turn `Indexing` to `Yes (No duplicates)`.

Comment: I tried the code but still had no luck.  I can send you all of the code, if you like?  Maybe this will help...

Comment: What issues are you having with the code I supplied?

Comment: It is not compiling.  Some of the statements are not recognized in the compiler.  I will dig a bit deeper today.

Comment: It was missing two closing parenthesis from what I could tell in the refactor. I'm not seeing any other issues.

Comment: cool.  I will try it out.  Thanks for all your help.

Comment: These at are the errors I get:

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1061 'OleDbParameterCollection' does not contain a definition for 'AddWIthValue' and no extension method 'AddWIthValue' accepting a first argument of type 'OleDbParameterCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) Serial Number Checker Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0103 The name 'ida' does not exist in the current context Serial Number Checker

Comment: Got it to work with your code.  Thank you so much for the awesome help